# Windows agent missing for zabbix 2.4.7

Tags: zabbix

I want to use zabbix latest version. However, windows agent is missing for zabbix 2.4.7
http://www.zabbix.com/download.php

Please suggest what can be done to get windows agent

Answer (score 0):

If the Windows agent is not available on the official download page, you can check it out from the official repository. There are precompiled agents available for Windows for each release. For instance:

```
$ svn co svn://svn.zabbix.com/tags/2.4.7/bin
```

This will give you a directory with precompiled Zabbix 2.4.7 agents for Windows, both 32-bit and 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can always find the latest precompiled Windows binaries inside the full sources package:
   just download the archive under **Zabbix Sources** section here:
   http://www.zabbix.com/download.php
   Untar the archive and you would find Windows .exe files under bin folder there
2. Alternatively, you can resort to using this unofficial but very helpful project:
   http://www.suiviperf.com/zabbix/index.php
   That always has the latest Windows binaries for Zabbix wrapped in msi or exe installer for convenience